# how to show gender dimension count of a specific video in youtube analytics API?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I am using youtube analytics api v1 to retrieve the videos details from youtube. I want to get gender dimension count but couldn't find relevant answer. However, I have succeeded to create a GET url to get other details like elapsedVideoTimeRatio, audienceWatchRatio, relativeRetentionPerformance of a given video id. Please take a look at below URL.

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel==**{ABC_CHANNEL}**&start-date=2018-01-04&end-date=2018-04-16&metrics=audienceWatchRatio,relativeRetentionPerformance&dimensions=elapsedVideoTimeRatio&filters=video==**{ABCXYZ}**&fields=columnHeaders,kind,rows&access_token=**{ACCESS_TOKEN}**

This URL gives me the details of mentioned parameters with no error. But whenever i try to change the **metrics** or **dimensions** parameters it gives me error. I want to know how to get analytics data of a particular video with ageGroup, gender dimension.

I am trying to make the GET request using below URL by changing the metrics and dimensions params.

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel==UCiqK9TkrbgO_i7h-XGExMXQ&start-date=2018-01-04&end-date=2018-04-16&metrics=viewerPercentage&dimensions=ageGroup,gender&filters=video==rUV78kBqdEs;audienceType==ORGANIC&fields=columnHeaders,kind,rows&access_token=ya29.GlufBf1Dc3u6TRsxYFLrSwQS08CcSB0_Dpxt4AbcWNSbMCaEG11jgdwubKxzXA2DsglpmQucmDdDi-k_VxFYljoga8r69-vj5G_i_O3GD0f_T9QHyZcAjG0ssbj5`

The above url gives the error response as given below.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "The query is not supported. Check the documentation at 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports for a list of supported queries."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The query is not supported. Check the documentation at 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports for a list of supported queries."
 }
}`
```

Please help.

Comment: how have you tried to change it? please edit your question and show us the request that you are making that fails and the error you are getting

Comment: @DalmTo I have edited my code. Please take a look.

Comment: remove the filters and try again https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#demographic-reports

Comment: Without filter param its working fine. However, its showing data data for whole channel. But i want the data of single video id rather than getting the data of whole channel. In filters i am passing video id as parameter(i.e video==rUV78kBqdEs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending `filters=video==rUV78kBqdEs;audienceType==ORGANIC` as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#demographic-reports) you can only send the following filters.

> Filters:
>
> - Use 0 or 1   country, province, continent, subContinent
> - Use 0 or 1    video, group
> - Use 0 or more liveOrOnDemand, subscribedStatus

Comment: Can you please describe in some more detail. what should be the exact value in filter?

Comment: I have removed `;audienceType==ORGANIC` from filters parameter. The error goes off with these changes. But the result is same as if i remove entire filters parameter from URL, No changes will reflect in response. I am not sure that i am going in right direction or not.

Comment: remove ;audienceType==ORGANIC you cant use it.   there is no other direction to go in.

Comment: Please see if following URL if valid `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel==MINE&start-date=2018-01-04&end-date=2018-04-16&metrics=viewerPercentage&dimensions=ageGroup,gender&filters=video==rUV78kBqdEs&fields=columnHeaders%2Ckind%2Crows&access_token=ya29.GlufBQDbvfooRp2cRRMJLiAidTgdhPPXv4fxC8N9xd2WLOQAp0T2lHFV9XfdcfcNM4zJ-sh42mlxACOVjixWQ0ZNuV-vh1gzMnOk54Jcy1x8HWg5v2_gLtAzW8iM`

Comment: Invalid Credentials means your access token has expired thats a diffrent issue.

Comment: Don't try to hit this in browser, I know the access token is expired in given url. You please take a look and check the URL parameters

Comment: @ManishVerma this request doesn't return any rows for me:


`{
      ids: 'channel==MINE',
      startDate: '2015-11-19',
      endDate: '2018-01-31',
      metrics: 'viewerPercentage',
      dimensions: 'ageGroup',
      maxResults: 200,
      filters: 'video==' + videoId
    }`

Comment: please open a new question and not post comments on unrelated issues